# How to put a zero knowledge verifier contract onto zkSync?

Tags: solidity, zero-knowledge, zksync

I want to place a zero-knowledge verifier contract on zkSync to verify some functions.

For example:

```
x^2 + x + 5 = 245
```

The answer is `15`, but I don't want people to see others transactions and copy it.

```js
function solve(uint256 x) external returns(bool){
 // pseudo code:
 if((x * x) + x + 5 == 256) {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

I'd rather have them submit a zk proof:

```js
function verifyProof(
        uint256[2] memory a,
        uint256[2][2] memory b,
        uint256[2] memory c,
        uint256[1] memory input
    ) public view returns (bool r) {
```

How would I generate such a function on zkSync?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a proof, you could use a tool like [hardhat-circom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-circom) (however it's no longer maintained), to combine your Circom & SnarkJS workflow. You'd need to:

1. Build a circom circuit to generate the proof
2. Compile the circuits
3. Generate wasm and zkey files
4. Use those to generate and output Verifier contracts

However, doing this on zkSync *as of writing* right now will be challenging, if not incredibly gas expensive, due to some precompiles not existing, including:

- [ecPairing](https://www.evm.codes/precompiled)

There are plans to add this next.

You can see the differences between the EVM and zkSync in the [zkSync docs here](https://docs.zksync.io/build/developer-reference/differences-with-ethereum.html#precompiles).